# Unable to burn .iso using Windows Disc Image Burner (Error code: 0x80004005)

Tags: windows, iso-image

When I try to burn a disc image file using Windows Disc Image Burner the burning fails and the Status says "The disc image didn't burn sucessfully because an error occured  (Error code: 0x80004005)".

I am using Windows 7, with a Dell Latitude 6250. The DVD Disc I'm trying to use is a Tayo Yuden DVD+R, and the image file was made with imgburn and is 4.11 GB in size.

I tried previously to burn a file folder to this same type of media, and although it burned, part of the disc was unreadable by windows 7. Thus, I've tried creating an .iso and burning it as an image with Windows Image Burner, so that afterwards it could be MD5 checksum verified.

If there are other details needed to answer this question please let me know and I will edit this post with them.

EDIT 11/27: These are unused media. IMGBURN completes verification sucessfully, and I've tested the disc it makes and it seems to be good (but how can I md5 checksum check it?)

Comment: Does this happen with every *.ISO file?

Comment: Are these unused media?

Comment: Does ImgBurn have the same problem?

Comment: I've had trouble trying to burn discs on Windows as well, then I tried InfraRecorder, and it worked great! What happens if you try this tool?

Comment: [Try another burning software](https://cdburnerxp.se/en/home), if you get the same error it most likely a defective optical drive.

Comment: Please use this one is the most easy ISO burner ever http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm

Comment: "certutil -hashfile filename.iso SHA512" - also try the same ISO file elsewhere.  (Don't just re-make it; I've seen the same command make different ISO files, so I guess some random data is frequently made.  Instead, transfer the file and check elsewhere.)  May want to verify that 7-Zip is happy with the ISO file.  7-zip.org download, then `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" t "filename.iso"`

Answer (score 0):

Some people seem to have this kind of problem with Daemon Tools or Alcohol 120%, and it can be fixed by removing sptd.sys, which means "SCSI Pass Through Direct Host". It's a driver used to emulate CD/DVD.
Here is a [link](http://forum.daemon-tools.cc/f19/how-remove-sptd-sys-system-24772/) to remove it.

However your problem seems specific to Windows Disc Image Burner that's why you should try others burning software before removing sptd.sys

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem using the burning program in Windows 10 (using the media creation tool to create a boot DVD) Solution? I uninstalled to reset the driver, it still gave the error, so I went to explorer, opened the properties of the drive, and allowed sharing. Amazing! has worked perfectly :-)